Open tank level measurement
I have a question regarding measurement of water level in an open tank with a pressure transmitter.
Normally this is pretty straight forward since I just use the simplified bernoulli equation $P = \rho g h$.
But I got a feedback that since the flow in this tank is so high that it does not provide correct height values, and I may have to use other ways of estimating the water height.
If I stick a pressure transmitter at the bottom here; is it correct that what that transmitter is reading is $P_T = P_{\text{static}}+P_{\text{dynamic}} = \left(\rho g h + P_{\text{atm}}\right)+ \dfrac{1}{2}\rho v^2$
And in this case the flow of water $v$ is so high that it is not negligible and gives me incorrect values?


You're right to consider the potential impact of flow velocity on the pressure reading, especially in a high-flow scenario. Typically, when measuring the water level in an open tank, the static pressure at the bottom, $P = \rho g h$, should suffice, as it relates directly to the height $h$ of the water column. However, if the flow within the tank is fast, the fluid velocity $v$ could indeed add a dynamic pressure component due to the Bernoulli effect.
The pressure transmitter at the bottom would then measure a total pressure $P_T$, which includes both static and dynamic pressure:
$P_T = P_{\text{static}} + P_{\text{dynamic}} = (\rho g h + P_{\text{atm}}) + \frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$
In this case, the added term $\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2$ represents the kinetic energy per unit volume of the fluid, contributing to the overall pressure reading. If $v$ is indeed significant, the transmitter could interpret this additional dynamic pressure as an increase in water height, leading to incorrect measurements.
To ensure accuracy, you might need to account for or measure the flow velocity separately. Alternatively, consider placing the sensor in a section where the flow is minimal to avoid this dynamic influence.
